# Dynamic Dropdown Menu Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am very familiar with programming, MySQL, PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, HTML and CSS, and this issue of mine has nothing to do with what I just mentioned. It all boils down to three things:

1. Defining a menu layout with link options.
2. Rendering a dropdown menu on-demand with position calculated live.
3. Determining if the current user with current session is owner of the object clicked.

**Nr. 2** is not a big problem, very simple indeed. **Nr.1 & 3** are a bit problematic. And it is this part that I do not fully understand, I know that for **Nr. 3** Ajax can be used to communicate with the PHP in the backend and determine ownership of an object through IDs.

As for **Nr.1** should this be put in PHP or as a JavaScript AMD definition, I am not so sure about this myself.

I hope things are much clearer now.

Comment: HTML usually shouldn't be in the response, but it is rendered after get a response. You can easily do DOM manipulation after Ajax calls and that's correct.

Comment: It all depends on what you want responsible for generating view data - your backend code, or your frontend code. It also depends on the architecture of your backend code and whether you're using an API to get just data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Ajax can be used to load any data (html also) it depends on the programmer that what he wants to do with the data. For example, if you send a request to server to send some html, and in response it sends HTML to you then you can just simply render that html code in your DOM. It is as simple as that...

Comment: I am aware that it is very simple to perform a GET request, and append the HTML to the DOM, DOM manipulation is simple as hell. However, I am more curious about menus, for example: if I am on Facebook, I post something and I them click an icon and a dropdown menu appears, one choice I have is: "Delete Post", if another user clicks on my post a dropdown menu appears, however, it doesn't include "Delete Post" since he isn't the owner, but I am. Now sure the menu is appended to the DOM. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying,,

Comment: But in the example image you shown above, that does not has to be done with ajax, that menu is made to append on DOM as soon as you click the icon. The yellow highlighted area you are seeing, is the result of appending of course. but the menus were loaded with the page and are made invisible to the user. they are set to be shown or displayed only when the user clicks the icon. The menus may be dynamic but the highlighted code you are seeing is because of simple javascript or jquery scripting.....

Comment: And for your example of facebook posts,, unlike your above picture, I'm sure the menu is loaded only when the user clicks the dropdown icon on the post, so when you are talking about the delete option, 

facebook already knows from which id the post was posted, so on user's wall faecbook already knows that the person is or is not the owner of the post and displays data accordingly, this can be done by simple server side session validation of the logged in user.

Comment: I know that the highlighted code is appended by jQuery or some other JavaScript Framework. I am NOT new to programming or web dev, but I want to know how BIG famous websites, like: Google, Twitter, YouTube, Quora and Facebook do something like this.

Comment: I think you know the concept or techniques behind dynamic loading, so as per your question,, for facebook it is explained in the links below :

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654613/does-facebook-use-comet-or-ajax-for-its-notifications)

[here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1497207)

this way facebook gets data from its servers,, ANd you know how to append data to DOM after getting the data from the server.

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with "Long Polling".

Comment: I think you might've looked at the wrong answer

Comment: I wasn't redirected here previously. I will read this now.

Comment: I have written a simple code for you,,, I'm sure this will clear all of your confusions.

as you have a confusion in Pt. 1 and Pt. 3. So for Pt.1, layout is defined with just html.

and for Pt.3, when the user clicks the menu button, the request goes for menu items to the server script. then the server script decides what items to send to the user. When the data is arrived, it is appended to DOM as you know... 

tell me your email address I will mail the file to you ,, I have tried to be as simple as possible and it works just like you want,,  so i hope it helps you.......

Comment: OOPS! I missed this, my e-mail is: anarki0999 {AT} gmail {.} com

Comment: Check your mail box mail from: pawansharma3303@gmail.com

Comment: Working of program:

there are two users : "owner" and "regular", Login with any of these users>>>

firstly the program finds out if the user is logged in or not,, if no then it shows login form and if yes then it shows the same menu button layout for both users. But when the user clicks the menu button, an ajax request is pulled which asks the program to get menu items for the logged in user,, then if the logged in user is "owner", then the php sends the menu items for owner in response of the ajax request and if the user is "regular" then the script sends menu for regular user, thats it

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I understand the code-snippet without running it. However, I already knew this part, account levels and groupings in PHP. I am more concerned with definitions of elements, and on-demand rendering. For example: FB returns the following, "for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"bootloadable":{},"ixData":{},"lid":"0"}", I do not see any HTML for the menu? Can you explain this part?

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the requirement that you should use an ajax call or just use jquery to append or show some html.

(For simplicity and for your question):
**Use Ajax:**
To get data from server.
Append html using ajax if the html contains the data which needs to be get from the server.

**Use Jquery:**
To append/show html which is present on page ,no need of ajax call.

Like for example in above quora dropdown ,
-There is no ajax when you click on that "..." image(Although you can use ajax here but it depends on the application requirement,here quora is getting this drpdown values on page load).
-There is ajax when you click on "Make anonymuous" ,"Add to reading list" etc etc.

Comment: LOL, I am not confused. I want to know how this is done, why aren't those menus preloaded on the DOM, instead they appear through an append to the DOM with position absolute and left top calculated live.

Comment: Ok ,I think i have wrong interpreted your question , but i have also explained that to you according to your question , hope you understand.See my edited answer.